# ThreadPoolExecutor task for downloading files in bulk downloads only last file in list

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, urllib, threadpoolexecutor

I have a file called `images.txt`, which is just a list of image URLs, one per line:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3e/Glenn_Jacobs_%2853122237030%29_-_Cropped.jpg/440px-Glenn_Jacobs_%2853122237030%29_-_Cropped.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/de/Kane2003.jpg/340px-Kane2003.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/Steel_Cage.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Kane_2008.JPG/340px-Kane_2008.JPG
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Brothers_of_Destruction.jpg/440px-Brothers_of_Destruction.jpg
```

I want to start a thread-pool executor with `20` worker threads that downloads each image in a separate thread, into a local subdirectory called "`images`". This is the code I am trying. Problem is - it prints that it is downloading all images, but ultimately only one image - the last one in the list, gets downloaded, rest are never downloaded.

```
from os import makedirs
from os.path import basename
from os.path import join
import shutil
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed

import requests

# load a file from a URL, returns content of downloaded file
def download_url(urlpath, dir):
    # Set the headers for the request
    headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }

    r = requests.get(urlpath, headers=headers, stream=True)
    filename = basename(urlpath)
    outpath = join(dir, filename)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(outpath, 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)  
 
# download one file to a local directory
def download_url_to_file(link, path):
    download_url(link, path)
    return link
 
# download all files on the provided webpage to the provided path
def getInBulk(filePath, path):
    # download the html webpage
    # create a local directory to save files
    makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
    # parse html and retrieve all href urls listed
    links = open(filePath).readlines()
    # report progress
    print(f'Found {len(links)} links')
    # create the pool of worker threads
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as exe:
        # dispatch all download tasks to worker threads
        futures = [exe.submit(download_url_to_file, link, path) for link in links]
        # report results as they become available
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            # retrieve result
            link = future.result()
            # check for a link that was skipped
            print(f'Downloaded {link} to directory')
 
PATH = 'images'
filePath = "images.txt"
getInBulk(filePath, PATH)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```py
for link in open('images.txt').readlines():
    print([link])
```

run this code and you will see that every line ends with a `\n` (newline) but the last.  so the first four get a response other than `200` (`r.status_code`).

simply changing this line:

```
links = [link.strip() for link in open(filePath).readlines()]
```

and your code worked for me.

> it prints that it is downloading all images

because the "target function" (`download_url_to_file`) you are calling just returns a string, which could say anything, rather than some meaningful value like the response code.

Comment: Wow. That is severely cool. Thanks a lot! And welcome to Stackoverflow!